# Writing an Installer for code that uses NUMPY > Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have written code for a friend that uses (it imports it in the first line) Numpy in order to mess around with quartic equations. This friend has absolutely no idea how to do anything with computers, so I was trying to make it so that he would not have to install the module.

I tried putting the folder for Numpy in the same folder in which the code is stored, but when I tried to run that it only brought up errors.

Is there a way to either do that correctly or else write a code that he can just execute that will install Numpy into his path?

Not sure if this is necessary, but here is the beginning of my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    from tkinter import *
```

Comment: [Why not compile it?](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) That way it just runs

Comment: If you copy your whole C:/Python36 folder (or wherever you have it installed) to his computer, it should work. I'm not sure the equivalents for Unix/ OSX